# How to handle JQuery form submit properly?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a function that captures data from a form, inserts in database then return response in a div.

While this works for inserting, I have a display issue.
I'm setting the response through `$(".articlebox").html(response);` which sets the response to all the `.articlebox` items on the page.

How can I avoid  this?

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".commentForm").bind('submit', function(){
    var usercomment = $(".articleComment").val();
    var categoryid = $(".categoryid").val();
    var userid = $(".userid").val();
    var ARID = $(".ARID").val();
    var dataString = 'userid='+ userid + '&articleComment='+ usercomment + '&ARID='+ ARID + '&categoryid='+ categoryid;

    // AJAX Code To Submit Form.
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "comment.php",
      data: dataString,
      cache: false,
      success: function(response){
        $(".articlebox").html(response);
        $(".commentForm").trigger("reset");
      }
    });

    return false;
  });
});
```

**EDIT display.php**

```
 <?php while($getcomments=mysqli_fetch_array($resultcomments)){?>
 <div class='row'>
<div class='articlebox'>
<span><?=$getcomments['ProfileName'];?> |  <?=$getcomments['DateTime'];?>  </span>
<p><?=$getcomments['Comments'];?> </p>
</div>
```

Comment: you need to post html

Comment: `.articlebox` is a collection of elements. Use a single element instead...

Comment: The jquery syntax that you are using will post to every element that has the class `articlebox`. If you want to post to only one, there are probably a couple ways to do it, but giving the element of interest an ID value, which has to be unique, and then writing to it will only post to one element, the one that has the `id="yourIDValue"` attribute.

Comment: Is the Ajax result the whole comment collection for all article too ?

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette: yes thats right thats my problem right now. The users comment on one articles and the comment shows on all articles thats not what I want.

Comment: You problem is not only on where to display the result then... Do you have a live link so I could understand what you try to do?

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette: well ive been trying to fix this for days now I dont know what to do. This only happens if I use AJAX. When I use plain PHP im okay, the comment goes to the right article. When I implement AJAX a lot of problem appears.

Comment: Continue in chat ? https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145081/ajax-talk-about-so-question-44171446

Answer (score 0):

get the index of the articlebox which you want to write in

then

$('.articlebox').eq(index).html(response)